# Storing sensor data for various sensor types

Tags: sql, database, api, sensors, sql-server-2016

I have a question about how best to store the sensor data produced when the types of sensors are different.

**A little bit of background:**

I have two different sensoring units.

One unit (lets say Unit Type A) has built in sensoring (temp, humidity etc) and produces a CSV string 12 in length in a fixed order, where all 12 values are of use to me.

The other unit (Unit type B) is a unit where you can plug in probes and energy moniting clamps etc, in all cases it produces a CSV string 13 in length, but if you only have two things connected, you only get useful information from two of the 13 CSV values. We have two different configurations of this unit we will use.

All of the sensors have an ID (given in the CSV string), I will be linking the sensor by ID to a room which is already in a database (SQL 2016) through a web UI (ASP.NET).

The types of queries I will be doing are "what is the current temp in room a", I will also need to query for trends such as "give me all the rooms with a high humidity average".

**My question**

Considering that I will have about 250 sensors at the moment, each posting through a web API around every 10 seconds or so, and I have currently two different types of CSV Strings (maybe more in the future), and in one case the CSV string will contain useful information in a different part of the CSV string than another, what would you recommend as a suitable table structure to support this? ideally in SQL server (maybe 2016 for JSON support?) as SQL Server is something I am more familar with, however if this is a badchoice of course I am open to your ideas.

I was trying to avoid a table 'per sensor type', as this seems messy, it would also make it harder to add different sensor types in the future without new tables etc.

I did consider having my API seperate to my web app, posting my sensors to it and have the API store the CSV 'as is' into a database, along with a 'sensor type' ID. I thought then I could post processing it in batches (service of some sort) using a stored procedure to inserting into my main database in batches as I thought this might reduce the API overhead some what.

**Database Structure**

A building has many rooms, a room has many sensors. A sensor has a type. I will keep tabs of the mapping between a rooms and a sensor IDs in a mapping table.

**Sensor Types explained**

Sensor type A has the following information:

1. Date (string)
2. Time (string)
3. SensorID (string)
4. Temp (decimal)
5. Humidity (decimal)
6. PIR Count (int)

Sensor B comes in two different configurations, in both cases the same CSV string is posted, the different will be in which values are used from it, but i want to store:

Config 1 (pipe temps)

1. DateTime (unix timestamp)
2. SensorID
3. Pipe Temp 1 (decimal)
4. Pipe Temp 2 (decimal)

Config 2 (Power monitoring)

1. DateTime (unix timestamp)
2. SensorID (string)
3. Power 1 (decimal)
4. Power 2 (decimal)
5. Power 3 (decimal)
6. Power 4 (decimal)

All sensors have the same common data:

1. DateTime
2. SensorID

I suppose one solution is to have a room have many 'sensor type A's' and many sensor type b's in config 1, and many sensor type b's in config 2 with each sensor type having its own table for its data, however I thought it would be great if I could just have the one table for all sensors in a sensor table, and give them a type from a type table, as this would be more flexible if/when adding more sensors. The downside to this approach is how when do i link to these different sensor data types/shapes

Thanks

Comment: A "sensor" table is possibly a red herring, since you're not really interested in sensors, but in "rooms", right?  (Although you'll likely need a sensor table anyways).  You **DO NOT** want to save a CSV string to the database, but rather a column per sensed item, some of which might be null - what happens if an individual sensor on Unit Type A malfunctions, by the way?  And actually, a web API or some sort of translation process to load into the database is a great idea.

Comment: I see your point about saving the sensed item rather than the CSV, Unit Type B may be reading pipe temps (in which case I want two values from the 13 long CSV string), or it might be setup to read power readings (4 readings per CSV line as it has 4 power readers) in which case I will a 13 long CSV string but I only want 4 things out of it. I will know how the sensor is being used (power or pipe temp), so i will know what values are of interest to be, should I be storing the of interest values as json? or as 'a sensor has one to many reads, a read has a reading type' (etc water pipe).

Comment: To expand on the database structure a little also, a building has many rooms, a room has many sensors (of different types) and a sensor type can be setup in different ways (but the ways are known). The 'different ways' simply just mean different values from the CSV string become either useful or of no interest. Different masks would be one way to discribe it I suppose.

Comment: You want to end up with a timestamped series of some sort, with fk links to room and sensor.  You don't want to store anything as JSON either if you can avoid it; instead you should be translating to table(s) with columns like `temperature_in_celsius`, etc.

Comment: The only problem is a sensor could be of "type a" in which case the columns required (power 1, power 2..) would be very different to one of "type b" (temp, humidity etc), I suppose it would be ok if the table with the read value had a column for every single possible reading type, for all sensor types, is that an acceptable solution?

Comment: ....you might want multiple tables.  Why don't you update your question with the type of information the sensors give you, and what they relate to (pipes, rooms, whatever)

Comment: Good idea, I have added the type information for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your basic options are [discussed in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database), but it's interesting to work the example.

Okay, let's go at this bit-by-bit.

> A building has many rooms

So right off, we know we have two tables:

```
Building
```

and

```
Room 
  --fk to Building
```

> a room has many sensors.

```
Sensor
  --fk to Room
```

(or, possibly, if sensors might monitor events from multiple rooms)

```
Sensor

Room_Sensor
  --fk to Room
  --fk to Sensor
```

> A sensor has a type.

```
Sensor
  --type id of some sort (manufacturer?)
```

> Sensor type A has the following information:

... and this is where it gets interesting.  Because, while it's true `Type A` *generates* this information, this is not the *state* of a `Type A`; it's the state of a `room`.

And that's the important part of this: databases are a repository of *state* (a series of states, here, given we have timestamps).

There's an additional problem, too - what happens if sensors are moved, or rooms are subdivided ("adding" two or more rooms that weren't previously there)?  So lets backtrack a little:

```
Room
  --fk to building

Sensor
  --type id of some sort, manufacturer info?

Room_Sensor
  --pk
  --fk to room
  --fk to sensor
  --createdAt timestamp
```

Note that `Room_Sensor` may have multiple copies of the same `(Room, Sensor)` relationship, changing over time (maybe a sensor was moved across the hallway for a week or something).

Now, what about the measured data?  You actually have several different "things" here:

```
Environment
  --fk to Room_Sensor
  --occurredAt timestamp
  --temperatureInCelsius
  --humidityInBar (or whatever other unit)
  --PIR (particulate?  please label your units)
```

(I'm assuming that the indexed items for `Type B` represent the same *measurement* of different *things*, which are supposed to be multiple rows, and which mean an additional table to use for foreign keys.  If they're instead different measurements of the same thing - inflow and outflow temperature, say - it's simpler)

```
Pipe

Pipe_Temperature
  --fk to pipe
  --fk to Room_Sensor
  --occurredAt timestamp
  --temperatureInCelsius
```

And

```
Electrical_Drop

Electrical_Drop_Draw
  --fk to Electrical_Drop
  --fk to Room_Sensor
  --occurredAt timestamp
  --consumptionInWatts
```

...yeah, that's probably what I'd start with.  With this sort of structure, the actual physical type of the sensor is irrelevant - we only care about the type of information it provides us.  Perhaps in the future `Type B` has new capability added to measure room temperature; if so, the database may remain the same, and the rows may be added to the existing tables.

Note that doing this requires you to have an API or loading program of some sort, but you'd most likely require one of those regardless.

Comment: This is great, I really like the way you model the enviroment as sensor type A is the only sensor type responsible for this. Pipe temps are more building specific so I suppose I could handle that like the above but linked to a building (which is made up of a collection of rooms). Thanks I think I have a clear picture of where to go now.

Comment: This looks to be a sensible structure and answer. however I would recommend OP research various open building standards such as gbxml, cobie, and BIM related standards, etc. Engineering generally follows: site, building, floor[s], zone, space, space type, equipment, device, protocol, data. In that order. Researching industry standards will allow for future legacy interoperability.

Comment: Good advice Radio, The structure of the building will follow IFC actually. I didnt include that information as I was interested in the sensor side of things and didnt want to scare people off with words like BIM and IFC but its a valid point.

Comment: For the REST API layer consider SlashDB. It automatically reflects your SQL model into an API for reading and writing. Particularly useful since your model is changing a lot at this stage and having to code the API layer by hand for each change is a big pain. Disclosure: SlashDB is my business. https://slashdb.com/